# How to get copy of variable for closure?

Tags: javascript, lambda, closures

What are the ways -- **except** of creating a proxy function -- to get a copy of the variable when defining lambda?

Consider:

```
for (....
{
   var something = ...
   var lambda = function() { ... something ... }
}
```

All lambdas will get the same `something`.

Or in other way -- is there any other way than creating proxy function?

Comment: If you declare `something` *inside* brackets, lambas *should* not get the same `something`.

Comment: is it proxy or prototype?

Comment: In javascript, functions are the only structures with their own scope. Therefore, for each iteration of the loop to have it's own `something`, you must introduce an inner function.

Comment: Scope is per function, thus I could have this `something` really outside the loop. In my case something was an object (`Audio`) with each iteration I created new one, but all lambdas had the same one. I am explaining, I am not surprised, this is how the closure on reference works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand right you want something like this:

```
for (....
{
   var something = ...
   var lambda = (function(smt){return function() { ... smt ... }})(something)
}
```

Comment: @greenoldman: what do you mean by "proxy function", and how does this answer not count as "creating a proxy function"?

Comment: @newacct, I can see it is wrapped by function (technically), but here it is as second lambda -- somehow I didn't find this trick, and I created the second **named** (i.e. regular) function. Thus when you look at the number of the functions -- the number of them is the same, there is no additional function you could call by accident (for example).